# How to save data in Pygame

Tags: python

What I want to do is to save a variable when I run the code again

Code:

```
a = 1
b = input("c or d")
if b == "c":
    a += 1
    print(f"you have {a} points")
if b == "d":
    a -= 1
    print(f"you have {a} points")
```

Still confused? The first time I run this, if I respond with "c", then the output should be "you have 2 points", the next time I run this and respond with "c", the output should be "you have 3 points". I tried to find tutorials but none of them were useful. Share the code here if you solve the issue

IMPORTANT:

1. I use PyCharm
2. Add the code along with your answer

Comment: if you just want to save a couple of values, you could use a txt file or pickle it.  for anything more complex, a database could be useful

Comment: It's not important that you use PyCharm and it's not important that you use `pygame`. You should read "[Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)" in the tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a database like SQLite3 or if you're on replit, you can use replit's db:

```py
from replit import db

db['save'] = data
```

replit's db work just like a dictionary except it saves.

Comment: Thanks, but sorry, I use PyCharm, not Replit. It's for a game I'm making on PyGame. Definitely will be useful one day though. If you know someone who uses PyCharm, contact them

Comment: And by the way add the code I posted too, sorry for not stating this in the question

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: This question has been answered.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).